# Java arithmetic increment operator

Tags: java, increment, operator-precedence, addition, postfix-operator

```
int a = 6;
int b  =  a + a++; 
answer is 12

int a = 6;
int  c  = a++ + a; 
answer is 13
```

why are the answers for b and c are different ?
since postfix has higher a precedence value, then the answer for both should be 13 right?

Comment: Look here: https://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/11precedence/.  Note that postfix and prefix operators both of higher precedence than "+" (like you said)..  Note, too, that postfix is left to right (hence "7 + 6"), like you'd expect... but prefix is right to left (hence 6 + 6, then increment).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first example, you incremented the value of `a` in the second operand, so it doesn't affect the value of the first operand.
But, in the second example, you incremented the value of `a` in the first operand, so it affects the value of the second operand.